# Rspec - Better way to stub a block and test the yielded body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to stub the `testBlock` block and directly test the inside of it. Here's my class

```
class MyClass
  def method1
    testBlock('parameter') do
      my_model.method2
    end
  end

  def testBlock(param)
    yield
  end
end
```

And here's the test

```
RSpec.describe MyClass do
  it 'calls method2' do
    allow(subject).to receive(:testBlock) { |&block| [1].each(&block) }

    expect(my_model).to receive(:method2)
    subject.method1
  end
end
```

The `{ |&block| [1].each(&block) }` is just a workaround to achieve my desired behavior, but is there a better a way to achieve this without replacing the block itself with `each` block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `each` with `block.call` or just remove the argument and `yield`.

I assume the actual implementation of `testBlock` is more complicated, because as-is, just `yield` is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you! yes, the actual implementation is quite complicated.